# Can a MacBook Air battery be replaced?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a MacBook Air which is an awesome computer, however I am curious what my options will be when the battery finally kicks the bucket. Can it be replaced?

Comment: You should defiantly go to the Apple store.

Answer (score 4):

[Apple will replace it](http://www.apple.com/support/macbookair/service/battery/) for $129 US (price varies by country), or you can do it yourself, following [iFixit's guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Battery/6359/1). However iFixit lists a *used* [2010/2011 MacBook Air battery for $99 US](http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Battery/IF188-070#installGuides), and if you mess up anything doing the repair, it won't be covered under warranty. If I were you, I'd spend the extra $30 and have Apple do it.

It's also worth noting that Apple has improved battery durability considerably over the past few years (I think ever since they went with the "non-removeable" batteries). [From Apple.com:](http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

> The built-in battery of your MacBook Pro or MacBook Air is designed to deliver up to 1000 full charge and discharge cycles before it reaches 80 percent of its original capacity.

One "cycle" is a full discharge and recharge - so going from 100% to 0%. Or Going 100% to 50% twice.

For comparison, the older batteries (and to my knowledge, most non-Apple batteries) were rated for 300 cycles. In my experience, the first 300 cycles on my MacBook Pro took about 2 to 3 years of pretty heavy use (you can keep track in the **System Information** app, under the *Power* section). 1000 cycles should last the usable life of an Air, unless you're in the 99th percentile of hard use.

Comment: Yep my older MacBook (the white plactic-book) battery completely died after ~340 cycles.

Comment: It should be noted of course that the price of a used MacBook Air will also vary by country.